# Java SOAPElement With Multiple Namespaces

Tags: java, xml, soap, namespaces

This is my first time working with SOAP requests and XML in general so I may be missing something obvious. I can not get one of a few namespaces to show in a SOAP element. I need this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/SoapEnvelope.xsd" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <cuns:HeaderInfo xmlns:cuns="http://website.com/cuns">
            <cuns:Field1>123456</cuns:Field1>
            <cuns:Field2>987654321</cuns:Field2>
        </cuns:HeaderInfo>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <n1:BodyField1
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://website.xsi/location" 
            xmlns:cuns="http://website.com/cuns" 
            xmlns:n1="http://website.com/n1" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Transaction>
                ...
            </Transaction>
```

But my output gives my this which is missing the xmlns:xsi despite there being xsi:schemaLocation on BodyField1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/SoapEnvelope.xsd" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <cuns:HeaderInfo xmlns:cuns="http://website.com/cuns">
            <cuns:Field1>123456</cuns:Field1>
            <cuns:Field2>987654321</cuns:Field2>
        </cuns:HeaderInfo>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <n1:BodyField1
            xmlns:cuns="http://website.com/cuns" 
            xmlns:n1="http://website.com/n1" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://website.xsi/location">
            <Transaction>
                ...
            </Transaction>
```

The xmlns:xsi deceleration works fine for the envelope and cuns and n1 appear under BodyField1. My code explicitly declares xmlns:xsi and then xsi:schema. I'm not sure why it would show 2 other namespaces and the schema but not the xsi namespace. I have tried different ordering of the namespace, but it doesn't seem to matter. Here is my code for the BodyField1:

```
public static void makeTransaction(Vector<Transaction> transactions, SOAPMessage message){

    DOMSource source = null;
    Element superRoot = null;
    SOAPBodyElement bodyRoot = null;
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = null;
    SOAPBody body = null;

    try {
        //Make the document
        envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
        body = envelope.getBody();

        Name n1 = envelope.createName("BodyField1", "n1", 
        "http://website.com/n1");
        bodyRoot = body.addBodyElement(n1);

        bodyRoot.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        bodyRoot.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:schemaLocation", 
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/SoapEnvelope.xsd");
        bodyRoot.addNamespaceDeclaration("cuns", "http://website.com/cuns");

    } catch (SOAPException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer though- if this helps others. I was hunting for solution for similar problem, in my case, xmlsns:xsi was coming but not the xsi:schemalocation. Below did the trick for me.

```
SOAPElement eleXSINs = envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
eleXSINsfor .setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:schemaLocation", "http://xxxxxx.xsd");
```